# JS script fires everytime an element is loaded in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to get my little js script to run once the entire dom or content of the aspx is loaded.

I have loaded the below:

[JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

and they still fire everytime an element is loaded.

I also tried

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            //Me Script!
        });
```

This kinda works it loades the entire page before running the script for the number of times per element.

Or if there is a work around for my script so that it still forces what I want. Which is just add two slashes to my chosen links. ie file://///jobs/year/etc

```
            if (isFirefox || isChrome) {
                //You can use what ever to detect links, you can do it by tag and get every link. 
                var linkmodify = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-folder-open");
                for (var i = 0; i < linkmodify.length; i++) {
                    var replacementLink = "";
                    link = linkmodify[i].href;
                    for (var j = 0; j < link.length; j++) {
                        if (j == 5) {
                            replacementLink += '//';
                        }
                        replacementLink += link[j];
                    }
                    linkmodify[i].href = replacementLink;
                }
            }
```

Currently the links only have the standard three slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var haveIDoneMyStuff = false;    
var myDOMLoadHandler = function(){
    if (!haveIDoneMyStuff){
        doMyStuff();
        haveIDoneMyStuff = true;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myDOMLoadHandler);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly didn't work, on an interesting not now it is consistently adding two extra slashes per element on the page `file:///////////////////////////////////////JOBS/2016/16105/`

Comment: See edited code. It's not pretty, but it will at least ensure that the code is running exactly once.